# n_jobs don't work in sklearn-classes

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Does anybody use "n_jobs" of sklearn-classes? I am work with sklearn in Anaconda 3.4 64 bit. Spyder version is 2.3.8. My script can't finish its execution after setting "n_jobs" parameter of some sklearn-class to non-zero value.Why is this happening?

Comment: If you are on Windows, then try to include in your script the following: `if __name__ == "__main__":`. It did the trick for me. I added it first thing in my script and then I added the rest of my code using indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Several scikit-learn tools such as GridSearchCV and cross_val_score rely internally on Python’s multiprocessing module to parallelize execution onto several Python processes by passing n_jobs > 1 as argument.

Taken from Sklearn documentation:

> The problem is that Python multiprocessing does a fork system call
>   without following it with an exec system call for performance reasons.
>   Many libraries like (some versions of) Accelerate / vecLib under OSX,
>   (some versions of) MKL, the OpenMP runtime of GCC, nvidia’s Cuda (and
>   probably many others), manage their own internal thread pool. Upon a
>   call to fork, the thread pool state in the child process is corrupted:
>   the thread pool believes it has many threads while only the main
>   thread state has been forked. It is possible to change the libraries
>   to make them detect when a fork happens and reinitialize the thread
>   pool in that case: we did that for OpenBLAS (merged upstream in master
>   since 0.2.10) and we contributed a patch to GCC’s OpenMP runtime (not
>   yet reviewed).